# AVL Tree Rotation Seg Fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

My Avl tree keeps getting a seg fault at the rotate parts

```
void leftRotate(AVLNode **rootptr){

AVLNode *temp1, *temp2;

if(rootptr!=NULL && *rootptr!=NULL && (*rootptr)->right!=NULL){
    temp1 = *rootptr;
    if(temp1->parent->left == temp1 && temp1->right != NULL) {              //Left rotate for left-right cases
        temp1->right->parent = temp1->parent;
        temp1->parent->left = temp1->right;

        temp1->parent = temp1->right;
        temp1->right->left = temp1;
        temp1->left = temp1->right = NULL;
        temp1 = temp1->parent;
    }else{                                  //Left rotate for right-right cases
        if(temp1->parent->parent == NULL){
            temp1->left = temp1->parent;
            temp1->left->parent = temp1;
            *rootptr = temp1;
            temp1->parent = NULL;
        }

    }   
    updateHeight(temp1->left);
    updateHeight(temp1);
}
}
```

The error specifically happens at this part.

```
if(temp1->parent->parent == NULL){
            temp1->left = temp1->parent;
            temp1->left->parent = temp1;
            *rootptr = temp1;
            temp1->parent = NULL;
        }
```

The left rotate for the right left case already works but the left rotate for the right right case keeps giving me a seg fault. I've edited it lots of times but I can't put the pivot's parent to its left child without the seg fault.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: How do you know that `temp1->parent` isn't `NULL`?